# PostgreSQL function runs much slower than direct query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

My problem started when I was trying to wrap a simple sql statement as a function. The request, which took several ms to complete, began to take seconds.
I read everything I could on google but it was all about using function parameters.
Then I got rid of the parameters, but that didn't solve the problem.

So, now I have the following SQL statement

```
select fn_tz(idata.system_timestamp), gp.zname, fc.*
from jv idata   
join gp on st_distance(waypoint,geom)=0
join fc ON 
    idata.fare_code = fc.fare_code  AND 
    fc.validity @> fn_tz(idata.system_timestamp)::date  and 
    fc.polygon_name = gp.name
where idata.item_id='21159704983720122917';
```

When I run this query directly it takes about 80ms to execute. But if I put **the same query without any modification** in the function body it takes about 10 sec!

Anyway, I've tried everything that came to my mind

1. Regular PLPGSQL function (`return query ...`)
2. Regular SQL function (`select ...`)
3. PLPGSQL function with dynamic SQL query (`return query execute 'select ...'`)
4. At long last i tried Prepare/execute statement

All above methods give the same result - 10 sec.

Then i run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE ...` on prepared statement but even from it's output I'm unable to understand why it runs 10 sec

```
Hash Join  (cost=75.05..962862.24 rows=110 width=8) (actual time=1.075..10290.527 rows=476091 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: ((idata.fare_code = fc.fare_code) AND (gp.name = (fc.polygon_name)::text))
  Join Filter: (fc.validity @> (fn_tz(idata.system_timestamp))::date)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..925098.69 rows=59399 width=54) (actual time=0.298..8300.070 rows=53922 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (st_distance(idata.waypoint, gp.geom) = '0'::double precision)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2212398
        ->  Seq Scan on jv idata  (cost=0.00..4402.99 rows=53999 width=54) (actual time=0.039..33.038 rows=53960 loops=1)
              Filter: (item_id = '21159704983720122917'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 3079
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..13.30 rows=220 width=64) (actual time=0.000..0.003 rows=42 loops=53960)
              ->  Seq Scan on gp  (cost=0.00..12.20 rows=220 width=64) (actual time=0.006..0.025 rows=42 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=40.22..40.22 rows=2322 width=16) (actual time=0.717..0.717 rows=2268 loops=1)
        Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 141kB
        ->  Seq Scan on fc  (cost=0.00..40.22 rows=2322 width=16) (actual time=0.008..0.332 rows=2322 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.008 ms
Execution Time: 10324.558 ms
```

Surprisingly, if I run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the original query, it also takes about 10 seconds and produces an almost identical execution plan.

My server - managed instance of Postgres 11.8 on Google Cloud Platform

What else can i do/try?

**Upd:**
It seems i need to accent - i'm not looking the way to improve the performance of query. Direct query runs 80 ms and i'm happy with this.
I want to find reason - why direct query runs **100 times(!)** quicker than function body.

Comment: What is `fn_tz(idata.system_timestamp)::date` ? Why do you need a function here?

Comment: Try to change `return query execute` to `return query` in your function code and compare execution times. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-control-structures.html#:~:text=RETURN%20QUERY%20has%20a%20variant,as%20in%20the%20EXECUTE%20command.

Comment: @ Slava Rozhnev `return query`  is my first option

Answer (score 2):

`fn_tz` might sap some 2 seconds of the performance, but the main problem is that you are using `st_distance` rather than `st_dwithin`, which can be supported with an index:

```
select fn_tz(idata.system_timestamp), gp.zname, fc.*
from jv idata   
join gp on st_dwithin(waypoint, geom, 0)
join fc ON 
    idata.fare_code = fc.fare_code  AND 
    fc.validity @> fn_tz(idata.system_timestamp)::date  and 
    fc.polygon_name = gp.name
where idata.item_id='21159704983720122917';
```

The index would be:

```
CREATE INDEX ON jv USING gist (waypoint);
```

Comment: my problem is not performance, but difference in perfomance between direct query and query in function body

Comment: You never posted the function, all I could go by was the execution plan. BTW, which PostgreSQL version is that?

Comment: Postgres version - 11.8